# C++ Cannot convert lambda to std::packaged_task in std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl

I did some testing with `std::packaged_task` and came across this problem.

```
std::packaged_task<int(void)> task([]() -> int { return 1; });
task();
```

compiles and calling `task()` calls the lambda. However, this does not compile:

```
std::pair<int, std::packaged_task<int(void)>> pair(15, []() -> int { return 15; });
pair.second();
```

because

> error C2664: '`std::pair<int,std::packaged_task<int (void)>>::pair(const std::pair<int,std::packaged_task<int (void)>> &)`': cannot convert argument 2 from '`main::<lambda_abbe6cccb9110894d95e872872ec1296>`' to '`const std::packaged_task<int (void)> &`'

This, however, does compile:

```
std::vector<std::packaged_task<int()>> v;
v.emplace_back([](){ return 1; })
```

Why can't I create a `pair`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor in question is an explicit constructor. You need to explicitly invoke it for this to compile:

```
std::pair<int, std::packaged_task<int(void)>> 
    pair(15, std::packaged_task<int(void)>{ []() -> int { return 15; } });
```

Or, better yet, use `std::make_pair`:

```
auto pair = 
    std::make_pair(15, std::packaged_task<int(void)>{ []() -> int { return 15; } });
```

The case with the `vector` works, because `emplace_back` forwards the arguments to the `value_type`'s constructor. If you tried with `push_back` it wouldn't work.